# Android L (5.0) does not search native libraries in “armeabi” or "armeabi-v7a" folder (UnsatisfiedLinkError) in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, java-native-interface, android-5.0-lollipop, unsatisfiedlinkerror

My app is using 2 native libraries, lets call them LibA.so and LibB.so. Previously my app was running well below kitkat OS without any problem.

Now It gives UnsatisfiedLinkError in Nexus 5 with OS 5.0(lollipop)
Both .so library are in armeabi folder.

So please give me common solution folder stucture to follow.

I am rather new to native libraries in android. Thanks in advance!

update:
It works fine now.
Got a solution by changing my LibA.so file links to Md5_init related calls.
In Os 5.0 google have made some changes in system lib calls
Thank you all for your support

Comment: Show us how you are loading the library. I have no problems even with external folder libraries.

Comment: I a m loading library in libs\armeabi-v7a\LibA.so....it gives warnig stated below........ LibA.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.........After that it gives me ....java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "MD5_Init" referenced by "LibA.so"...

Comment: Why folder armeabi-v7a instead armeabi?

Comment: Put the code where you load the libraries.

Comment: i am loading the file using System.loadLibrary(so_name);...my app is live for 3 years in playstore,its running well with less than 5.0 lollipop OS., it is giving this error in latest 5.0 nexus devices only. there might be some md5_init file is missing in OS as stated in below answer.

Comment: If your app is named libcool.so your code must be `System.loadLibrary("cool");` Is it? Is your library file name all in lowercase? Is md5_init one of your functions in your library or in some part of your code? I'm trying hard to figure out, but there is no too much information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: It works fine now. Got a solution by changing my LibA.so file links to Md5_init related calls. In Os 5.0 google have made some changes in system lib calls to md5_init file
 Thank you all for your support

Comment: Post your Android.mk for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

From your error description I can see that library **LibA.so** not loaded due to it uses some **MD5** code which is not available - not linked in.
For example you may use other native shared library with MD5 sources linked in during build (as shared library) - but you not copied this shared library to target application **libs** folder.

I am not sure that implementation of **MD5** related functions included into recent Android NDK. And also may be it was part of some android system shared libraries for previous versions and it was removed from Android L.

So you need to check references from your C++/C code to MD5 related functions and found where sources are stored/linked.

I may provide links for functions list which is exported from **libc.so** for android-17 for example and android-L:
[Android-17 LIBC functions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/797351fd3bbb8fe517afafdd5095fd740387e7a4/ndk/platforms/android-17/arch-x86/symbols/libc.so.functions.txt) vs [Android-L LIBC functions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/797351fd3bbb8fe517afafdd5095fd740387e7a4/ndk/platforms/android-L/arch-arm/symbols/libc.so.functions.txt)

And as you also may see - MD5 related functions **are absent in shared libraries for L** - so I believe that you have to include sources for those features (MD5) into your dynamic library.

Comment: Here is the commit: [6740163  _Remove the MD5 implementation that was only used by toolbox._ by Elliott Hughes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/67401638a92abd52e5896183e851b1b097da07ac).

Comment: The missing MD5 is now in librypto.so, and has always been there.

Comment: so how can i add MD5_init files in my libraries as it is missing in Android L OS?

Comment: As I cheked - in recent Android NDK R10C absent shared libraries with implementation of MD5 related functions (MD5_Init, etc). I believe you need to include sources for MD5 functions directly in your library or link another static library (build for Android) which already has such functions. For example as @Alex mentioned - you may use libCrypto from OpenSSL built for android.

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work by including these 3 files in my project and adding md5.c to Android.mk LOCAL_SRC_FILES list.

md5.h, md5.c, hash.h

---

md5.h

```
/* $Heimdal: md5.h,v 1.8 2001/01/29 02:08:57 assar Exp $
   $NetBSD: md5.h,v 1.1.1.4 2002/09/12 12:41:42 joda Exp $ */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH 16

struct md5 {
  unsigned int sz[2];
  u_int32_t counter[4];
  unsigned char save[64];
};
typedef struct md5 MD5_CTX;
void MD5_Init (struct md5 *m);
void MD5_Update (struct md5 *m, const void *p, size_t len);
void MD5_Final (void *res, struct md5 *m); /* u_int32_t res[4] */
```

---

md5.c

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995 - 2001 Kungliga Tekniska Högskolan
 * (Royal Institute of Technology, Stockholm, Sweden).
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * 3. Neither the name of the Institute nor the names of its contributors
 *    may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
 *    without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE INSTITUTE AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
 * ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE INSTITUTE OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
 * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
 * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS
 * OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY
 * OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF
 * SUCH DAMAGE.
 */
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
__RCSID("$Heimdal: md5.c,v 1.15 2001/01/29 04:33:44 assar Exp $"
        "$NetBSD: md5.c,v 1.1.1.4 2002/09/12 12:41:42 joda Exp $");
#endif
#include <endian.h>
#include "md5.h"
#include "hash.h"
#define A m->counter[0]
#define B m->counter[1]
#define C m->counter[2]
#define D m->counter[3]
#define X data
void MD5_Init(struct md5 *m) {
    m->sz[0] = 0;
    m->sz[1] = 0;
    D = 0x10325476;
    C = 0x98badcfe;
    B = 0xefcdab89;
    A = 0x67452301;
}
#define F(x,y,z) CRAYFIX((x & y) | (~x & z))
#define G(x,y,z) CRAYFIX((x & z) | (y & ~z))
#define H(x,y,z) (x ^ y ^ z)
#define I(x,y,z) CRAYFIX(y ^ (x | ~z))
#define DOIT(a,b,c,d,k,s,i,OP) \
a = b + cshift(a + OP(b,c,d) + X[k] + (i), s)
#define DO1(a,b,c,d,k,s,i) DOIT(a,b,c,d,k,s,i,F)
#define DO2(a,b,c,d,k,s,i) DOIT(a,b,c,d,k,s,i,G)
#define DO3(a,b,c,d,k,s,i) DOIT(a,b,c,d,k,s,i,H)
#define DO4(a,b,c,d,k,s,i) DOIT(a,b,c,d,k,s,i,I)
static inline void calc(struct md5 *m, u_int32_t *data) {
    u_int32_t AA, BB, CC, DD;
    AA = A;
    BB = B;
    CC = C;
    DD = D;
    /* Round 1 */
    DO1(A, B, C, D, 0, 7, 0xd76aa478);
    DO1(D, A, B, C, 1, 12, 0xe8c7b756);
    DO1(C, D, A, B, 2, 17, 0x242070db);
    DO1(B, C, D, A, 3, 22, 0xc1bdceee);
    DO1(A, B, C, D, 4, 7, 0xf57c0faf);    
    DO1(D, A, B, C, 5, 12, 0x4787c62a);
    DO1(C, D, A, B, 6, 17, 0xa8304613);
    DO1(B, C, D, A, 7, 22, 0xfd469501);
    DO1(A, B, C, D, 8, 7, 0x698098d8);
    DO1(D, A, B, C, 9, 12, 0x8b44f7af);
    DO1(C, D, A, B, 10, 17, 0xffff5bb1);
    DO1(B, C, D, A, 11, 22, 0x895cd7be);
    DO1(A, B, C, D, 12, 7, 0x6b901122);
    DO1(D, A, B, C, 13, 12, 0xfd987193);
    DO1(C, D, A, B, 14, 17, 0xa679438e);
    DO1(B, C, D, A, 15, 22, 0x49b40821);
    /* Round 2 */
    DO2(A, B, C, D, 1, 5, 0xf61e2562);
    DO2(D, A, B, C, 6, 9, 0xc040b340);
    DO2(C, D, A, B, 11, 14, 0x265e5a51);
    DO2(B, C, D, A, 0, 20, 0xe9b6c7aa);
    DO2(A, B, C, D, 5, 5, 0xd62f105d);
    DO2(D, A, B, C, 10, 9, 0x2441453);
    DO2(C, D, A, B, 15, 14, 0xd8a1e681);
    DO2(B, C, D, A, 4, 20, 0xe7d3fbc8);
    DO2(A, B, C, D, 9, 5, 0x21e1cde6);
    DO2(D, A, B, C, 14, 9, 0xc33707d6);
    DO2(C, D, A, B, 3, 14, 0xf4d50d87);
    DO2(B, C, D, A, 8, 20, 0x455a14ed);
    DO2(A, B, C, D, 13, 5, 0xa9e3e905);
    DO2(D, A, B, C, 2, 9, 0xfcefa3f8);
    DO2(C, D, A, B, 7, 14, 0x676f02d9);
    DO2(B, C, D, A, 12, 20, 0x8d2a4c8a);
    /* Round 3 */
    DO3(A, B, C, D, 5, 4, 0xfffa3942);
    DO3(D, A, B, C, 8, 11, 0x8771f681);
    DO3(C, D, A, B, 11, 16, 0x6d9d6122);
    DO3(B, C, D, A, 14, 23, 0xfde5380c);
    DO3(A, B, C, D, 1, 4, 0xa4beea44);
    DO3(D, A, B, C, 4, 11, 0x4bdecfa9);
    DO3(C, D, A, B, 7, 16, 0xf6bb4b60);
    DO3(B, C, D, A, 10, 23, 0xbebfbc70);
    DO3(A, B, C, D, 13, 4, 0x289b7ec6);
    DO3(D, A, B, C, 0, 11, 0xeaa127fa);
    DO3(C, D, A, B, 3, 16, 0xd4ef3085);
    DO3(B, C, D, A, 6, 23, 0x4881d05);
    DO3(A, B, C, D, 9, 4, 0xd9d4d039);
    DO3(D, A, B, C, 12, 11, 0xe6db99e5);
    DO3(C, D, A, B, 15, 16, 0x1fa27cf8);
    DO3(B, C, D, A, 2, 23, 0xc4ac5665);
    /* Round 4 */
    DO4(A, B, C, D, 0, 6, 0xf4292244);
    DO4(D, A, B, C, 7, 10, 0x432aff97);
    DO4(C, D, A, B, 14, 15, 0xab9423a7);
    DO4(B, C, D, A, 5, 21, 0xfc93a039);
    DO4(A, B, C, D, 12, 6, 0x655b59c3);
    DO4(D, A, B, C, 3, 10, 0x8f0ccc92);
    DO4(C, D, A, B, 10, 15, 0xffeff47d);
    DO4(B, C, D, A, 1, 21, 0x85845dd1);
    DO4(A, B, C, D, 8, 6, 0x6fa87e4f);
    DO4(D, A, B, C, 15, 10, 0xfe2ce6e0);
    DO4(C, D, A, B, 6, 15, 0xa3014314);
    DO4(B, C, D, A, 13, 21, 0x4e0811a1);
    DO4(A, B, C, D, 4, 6, 0xf7537e82);
    DO4(D, A, B, C, 11, 10, 0xbd3af235);
    DO4(C, D, A, B, 2, 15, 0x2ad7d2bb);
    DO4(B, C, D, A, 9, 21, 0xeb86d391);
    A += AA;
    B += BB;
    C += CC;
    D += DD;
}
/*
 * From `Performance analysis of MD5' by Joseph D. Touch <touch@isi.edu>
 */
#if !defined(__BYTE_ORDER) || !defined (__BIG_ENDIAN)
#error __BYTE_ORDER macros not defined
#endif
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
static inline u_int32_t swap_u_int32_t(u_int32_t t) {
    u_int32_t temp1, temp2;
    temp1 = cshift(t, 16);
    temp2 = temp1 >> 8;
    temp1 &= 0x00ff00ff;
    temp2 &= 0x00ff00ff;
    temp1 <<= 8;
    return temp1 | temp2;
}
#endif
struct x32 {
    unsigned int a :32;
    unsigned int b :32;
};
void MD5_Update(struct md5 *m, const void *v, size_t len) {
    const unsigned char *p = v;
    size_t old_sz = m->sz[0];
    size_t offset;
    m->sz[0] += len * 8;
    if (m->sz[0] < old_sz)
        ++m->sz[1];
    offset = (old_sz / 8) % 64;
    while (len > 0) {
        size_t l = min(len, 64 - offset);
        memcpy(m->save + offset, p, l);
        offset += l;
        p += l;
        len -= l;
        if (offset == 64) {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
            int i;
            u_int32_t current[16];
            struct x32 *u = (struct x32*) m->save;
            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                current[2 * i + 0] = swap_u_int32_t(u[i].a);
                current[2 * i + 1] = swap_u_int32_t(u[i].b);
            }
            calc(m, current);
#else
            calc(m, (u_int32_t*)m->save);
#endif
            offset = 0;
        }
    }
}
void MD5_Final(void *res, struct md5 *m) {
    unsigned char zeros[72];
    unsigned offset = (m->sz[0] / 8) % 64;
    unsigned int dstart = (120 - offset - 1) % 64 + 1;
    *zeros = 0x80;
    memset(zeros + 1, 0, sizeof(zeros) - 1);
    zeros[dstart + 0] = (m->sz[0] >> 0) & 0xff;
    zeros[dstart + 1] = (m->sz[0] >> 8) & 0xff;
    zeros[dstart + 2] = (m->sz[0] >> 16) & 0xff;
    zeros[dstart + 3] = (m->sz[0] >> 24) & 0xff;
    zeros[dstart + 4] = (m->sz[1] >> 0) & 0xff;
    zeros[dstart + 5] = (m->sz[1] >> 8) & 0xff;
    zeros[dstart + 6] = (m->sz[1] >> 16) & 0xff;
    zeros[dstart + 7] = (m->sz[1] >> 24) & 0xff;
    MD5_Update(m, zeros, dstart + 8);
    {
        int i;
        unsigned char *r = (unsigned char *) res;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            r[4 * i] = m->counter[i] & 0xFF;
            r[4 * i + 1] = (m->counter[i] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            r[4 * i + 2] = (m->counter[i] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            r[4 * i + 3] = (m->counter[i] >> 24) & 0xFF;
        }
    }
#if 0
    {
        int i;
        u_int32_t *r = (u_int32_t *)res;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        r[i] = swap_u_int32_t (m->counter[i]);
    }
#endif
}
```

---

hash.h

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1999 Kungliga Tekniska Högskolan
 * (Royal Institute of Technology, Stockholm, Sweden).
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * 3. Neither the name of KTH nor the names of its contributors may be
 *    used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without
 *    specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY KTH AND ITS CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND ANY
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL KTH OR ITS CONTRIBUTORS BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
 * SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR
 * BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR
 * OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF
 * ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. */
/* $Heimdal: hash.h,v 1.1 1999/03/22 19:16:25 joda Exp $
   $NetBSD: hash.h,v 1.1.1.3 2002/09/12 12:41:42 joda Exp $ */
/* stuff in common between md4, md5, and sha1 */
#ifndef __hash_h__
#define __hash_h__
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(b):(a))
#endif
/* Vector Crays doesn't have a good 32-bit type, or more precisely,
   int32_t as defined by <bind/bitypes.h> isn't 32 bits, and we don't
   want to depend in being able to redefine this type.  To cope with
   this we have to clamp the result in some places to [0,2^32); no
   need to do this on other machines.  Did I say this was a mess?
   */
#ifdef _CRAY
#define CRAYFIX(X) ((X) & 0xffffffff)
#else
#define CRAYFIX(X) (X)
#endif
static inline u_int32_t
cshift (u_int32_t x, unsigned int n)
{
    x = CRAYFIX(x);
    return CRAYFIX((x << n) | (x >> (32 - n)));
}
#endif /* __hash_h__ */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull `libcrypto.so` from your device. It is not necessary to look for a Lollipop version. In your **Android.mk**, use

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lcrypto
```

Ignore the NDK warning about using non-official libraries. You should not ship this `libcrypto.so` with your APK, just like you don't ship `libm.so`. See more here: *[WARNING: …/Android.mk: non-system libraries in linker flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663989/warning-android-mk-non-system-libraries-in-linker-flags)*