# Android 5.0 lollipop dlopen(RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "MD5_Init"

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, ubuntu-14.04

i using md5 in `channelReceiver.c` file using jni

```
MD5_CTX td; 
MD5_Init(&td);
block = malloc(176);
MD5_Update(&td, block, 176);
MD5_Final(md5_result, &td);
```

Android one strange issue found when i am running my application in android 5.0 lollipop i found this error

```
dlopen("libchannelReceiver.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "MD5_Init" referenced by libchannelReceiver.so
```

before lollipop version its working fine.

so i am trying to `#include <openssl/md5.h>` in `channelReceiver.c`, but i found some other issue here

```
fatal error: openssl/md5.h: No such file or directory #include <openssl/md5.h>
```

i am working on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: See _[Android L (5.0) does not search native libraries in “armeabi” or “armeabi-v7a” folder (UnsatisfiedLinkError) in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27119623/)_. You can find MD5 on Lollipop, but not in `libc`. You should link against `libcrypto`. The headers have not changed.

Answer (score -1):

Solved this issue while we are running in Android Lollipop, MD5 removed from that, so we have to put this source code inside our application package.  create md5.h and md5.c

md5.h

```
 #ifndef MD5_H
 #define MD5_H

 #ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
 #  include <config.h>
 #endif

 #include <sys/types.h>

 #define MD5_HASHBYTES 16

 typedef struct MD5Context {
         u_int32_t buf[4];
         u_int32_t bits[2];
         unsigned char in[64];
 } MD5_CTX;

 char* lutil_md5_file(const char *filename, char *buf);
 char* lutil_md5_data(const unsigned char *data, unsigned int len, char *buf);

 #endif /* MD5_H */
```

md5.c

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
 #  include <config.h>
 #endif

 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #include "md5.h"
 #ifdef WITH_DMALLOC
 #  include <dmalloc.h>
 #endif

 static void MD5Init(MD5_CTX *context);
 static void MD5Update(MD5_CTX *context, unsigned char const *buf, unsigned len);
 static void MD5Final(unsigned char digest[MD5_HASHBYTES], MD5_CTX *context);
 static void MD5Transform(u_int32_t buf[4], u_int32_t const in[16]);
 static char* MD5End(MD5_CTX *, char *);


 #if __BYTE_ORDER == 1234
 #define byteReverse(buf, len)   /* Nothing */
 #else
 void byteReverse(unsigned char *buf, unsigned longs);

 /*
  * Note: this code is harmless on little-endian machines.
  */
 void byteReverse(unsigned char *buf, unsigned longs)
 {
     u_int32_t t;
     do {
         t = (u_int32_t) ((unsigned) buf[3] << 8 | buf[2]) << 16 |
             ((unsigned) buf[1] << 8 | buf[0]);
         *(u_int32_t *) buf = t;
         buf += 4;
     } while (--longs);
 }
 #endif /* ! __BYTE_ORDER == 1234 */




 char *
 lutil_md5_file (const char *filename, char *buf)
 {
     unsigned char buffer[BUFSIZ]; 
     MD5_CTX ctx;
     int f,i,j;

     MD5Init(&ctx);
     f = open(filename,O_RDONLY);
     if (f < 0) return 0;
     while ((i = read(f,buffer,sizeof buffer)) > 0) {
                 MD5Update(&ctx,buffer,i);
     }
     j = errno;
     close(f);
     errno = j;
     if (i < 0) return 0;
     return MD5End(&ctx, buf);
 }

 char *
 lutil_md5_data (const unsigned char *data, unsigned int len, char *buf)
 {
     MD5_CTX ctx;

     MD5Init(&ctx);
     MD5Update(&ctx,data,len);
     return MD5End(&ctx, buf);
 }


 /* Non-Interface Methods */

 /* from md5hl.c */

 char *
 MD5End(MD5_CTX *ctx, char *buf)
 {
     int i;
     unsigned char digest[MD5_HASHBYTES];
     static const char hex[]="0123456789abcdef";

     if (!buf)
         buf = malloc(33);
     if (!buf)
         return 0;
     MD5Final(digest,ctx);
     for (i=0;i<MD5_HASHBYTES;i++) {
         buf[i+i] = hex[digest[i] >> 4];
         buf[i+i+1] = hex[digest[i] & 0x0f];
     }
     buf[i+i] = '\0';
     return buf;
 }

 /*
  * Start MD5 accumulation.  Set bit count to 0 and buffer to mysterious
  * initialization constants.
  */
 void MD5Init(MD5_CTX *ctx)
 {
     ctx->buf[0] = 0x67452301;
     ctx->buf[1] = 0xefcdab89;
     ctx->buf[2] = 0x98badcfe;
     ctx->buf[3] = 0x10325476;

     ctx->bits[0] = 0;
     ctx->bits[1] = 0;
 }

 /*
  * Update context to reflect the concatenation of another buffer full
  * of bytes.
  */
 void MD5Update(MD5_CTX *ctx, unsigned char const *buf, unsigned len)
 {
     u_int32_t t;

     /* Update bitcount */

     t = ctx->bits[0];
     if ((ctx->bits[0] = t + ((u_int32_t) len << 3)) < t)
         ctx->bits[1]++;         /* Carry from low to high */
     ctx->bits[1] += len >> 29;

     t = (t >> 3) & 0x3f;        /* Bytes already in shsInfo->data */

     /* Handle any leading odd-sized chunks */

     if (t) {
         unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) ctx->in + t;

         t = 64 - t;
         if (len < t) {
             memcpy(p, buf, len);
             return;
         }
         memcpy(p, buf, t);
         byteReverse(ctx->in, 16);
         MD5Transform(ctx->buf, (u_int32_t *) ctx->in);
         buf += t;
         len -= t;
     }
     /* Process data in 64-byte chunks */

     while (len >= 64) {
         memcpy(ctx->in, buf, 64);
         byteReverse(ctx->in, 16);
         MD5Transform(ctx->buf, (u_int32_t *) ctx->in);
         buf += 64;
         len -= 64;
     }

     /* Handle any remaining bytes of data. */

     memcpy(ctx->in, buf, len);
 }

 /*
  * Final wrapup - pad to 64-byte boundary with the bit pattern 
  * 1 0* (64-bit count of bits processed, MSB-first)
  */
 void MD5Final(unsigned char digest[16], MD5_CTX *ctx)
 {
     unsigned count;
     unsigned char *p;

     /* Compute number of bytes mod 64 */
     count = (ctx->bits[0] >> 3) & 0x3F;

     /* Set the first char of padding to 0x80.  This is safe since there is
        always at least one byte free */
     p = ctx->in + count;
     *p++ = 0x80;

     /* Bytes of padding needed to make 64 bytes */
     count = 64 - 1 - count;

     /* Pad out to 56 mod 64 */
     if (count < 8) {
         /* Two lots of padding:  Pad the first block to 64 bytes */
         memset(p, 0, count);
         byteReverse(ctx->in, 16);
         MD5Transform(ctx->buf, (u_int32_t *) ctx->in);

         /* Now fill the next block with 56 bytes */
         memset(ctx->in, 0, 56);
     } else {
         /* Pad block to 56 bytes */
         memset(p, 0, count - 8);
     }
     byteReverse(ctx->in, 14);

     /* Append length in bits and transform */
     ((u_int32_t *) ctx->in)[14] = ctx->bits[0];
     ((u_int32_t *) ctx->in)[15] = ctx->bits[1];

     MD5Transform(ctx->buf, (u_int32_t *) ctx->in);
     byteReverse((unsigned char *) ctx->buf, 4);
     memcpy(digest, ctx->buf, 16);
     memset((char *) ctx, 0, sizeof(ctx));       /* In case it's sensitive */
 }

 /* The four core functions - F1 is optimized somewhat */

 /* #define F1(x, y, z) (x & y | ~x & z) */
 #define F1(x, y, z) (z ^ (x & (y ^ z)))
 #define F2(x, y, z) F1(z, x, y)
 #define F3(x, y, z) (x ^ y ^ z)
 #define F4(x, y, z) (y ^ (x | ~z))

 /* This is the central step in the MD5 algorithm. */
 #define MD5STEP(f, w, x, y, z, data, s) \
         ( w += f(x, y, z) + data,  w = w<<s | w>>(32-s),  w += x )

 /*
  * The core of the MD5 algorithm, this alters an existing MD5 hash to
  * reflect the addition of 16 longwords of new data.  MD5Update blocks
  * the data and converts bytes into longwords for this routine.
  */
 void MD5Transform(u_int32_t buf[4], u_int32_t const in[16])
 {
     register u_int32_t a, b, c, d;

     a = buf[0];
     b = buf[1];
     c = buf[2];
     d = buf[3];

     MD5STEP(F1, a, b, c, d, in[0] + 0xd76aa478, 7);
     MD5STEP(F1, d, a, b, c, in[1] + 0xe8c7b756, 12);
     MD5STEP(F1, c, d, a, b, in[2] + 0x242070db, 17);
     MD5STEP(F1, b, c, d, a, in[3] + 0xc1bdceee, 22);
     MD5STEP(F1, a, b, c, d, in[4] + 0xf57c0faf, 7);
     MD5STEP(F1, d, a, b, c, in[5] + 0x4787c62a, 12);
     MD5STEP(F1, c, d, a, b, in[6] + 0xa8304613, 17);
     MD5STEP(F1, b, c, d, a, in[7] + 0xfd469501, 22);
     MD5STEP(F1, a, b, c, d, in[8] + 0x698098d8, 7);
     MD5STEP(F1, d, a, b, c, in[9] + 0x8b44f7af, 12);
     MD5STEP(F1, c, d, a, b, in[10] + 0xffff5bb1, 17);
     MD5STEP(F1, b, c, d, a, in[11] + 0x895cd7be, 22);
     MD5STEP(F1, a, b, c, d, in[12] + 0x6b901122, 7);
     MD5STEP(F1, d, a, b, c, in[13] + 0xfd987193, 12);
     MD5STEP(F1, c, d, a, b, in[14] + 0xa679438e, 17);
     MD5STEP(F1, b, c, d, a, in[15] + 0x49b40821, 22);

     MD5STEP(F2, a, b, c, d, in[1] + 0xf61e2562, 5);
     MD5STEP(F2, d, a, b, c, in[6] + 0xc040b340, 9);
     MD5STEP(F2, c, d, a, b, in[11] + 0x265e5a51, 14);
     MD5STEP(F2, b, c, d, a, in[0] + 0xe9b6c7aa, 20);
     MD5STEP(F2, a, b, c, d, in[5] + 0xd62f105d, 5);
     MD5STEP(F2, d, a, b, c, in[10] + 0x02441453, 9);
     MD5STEP(F2, c, d, a, b, in[15] + 0xd8a1e681, 14);
     MD5STEP(F2, b, c, d, a, in[4] + 0xe7d3fbc8, 20);
     MD5STEP(F2, a, b, c, d, in[9] + 0x21e1cde6, 5);
     MD5STEP(F2, d, a, b, c, in[14] + 0xc33707d6, 9);
     MD5STEP(F2, c, d, a, b, in[3] + 0xf4d50d87, 14);
     MD5STEP(F2, b, c, d, a, in[8] + 0x455a14ed, 20);
     MD5STEP(F2, a, b, c, d, in[13] + 0xa9e3e905, 5);
     MD5STEP(F2, d, a, b, c, in[2] + 0xfcefa3f8, 9);
     MD5STEP(F2, c, d, a, b, in[7] + 0x676f02d9, 14);
     MD5STEP(F2, b, c, d, a, in[12] + 0x8d2a4c8a, 20);

     MD5STEP(F3, a, b, c, d, in[5] + 0xfffa3942, 4);
     MD5STEP(F3, d, a, b, c, in[8] + 0x8771f681, 11);
     MD5STEP(F3, c, d, a, b, in[11] + 0x6d9d6122, 16);
     MD5STEP(F3, b, c, d, a, in[14] + 0xfde5380c, 23);
     MD5STEP(F3, a, b, c, d, in[1] + 0xa4beea44, 4);
     MD5STEP(F3, d, a, b, c, in[4] + 0x4bdecfa9, 11);
     MD5STEP(F3, c, d, a, b, in[7] + 0xf6bb4b60, 16);
     MD5STEP(F3, b, c, d, a, in[10] + 0xbebfbc70, 23);
     MD5STEP(F3, a, b, c, d, in[13] + 0x289b7ec6, 4);
     MD5STEP(F3, d, a, b, c, in[0] + 0xeaa127fa, 11);
     MD5STEP(F3, c, d, a, b, in[3] + 0xd4ef3085, 16);
     MD5STEP(F3, b, c, d, a, in[6] + 0x04881d05, 23);
     MD5STEP(F3, a, b, c, d, in[9] + 0xd9d4d039, 4);
     MD5STEP(F3, d, a, b, c, in[12] + 0xe6db99e5, 11);
     MD5STEP(F3, c, d, a, b, in[15] + 0x1fa27cf8, 16);
     MD5STEP(F3, b, c, d, a, in[2] + 0xc4ac5665, 23);

     MD5STEP(F4, a, b, c, d, in[0] + 0xf4292244, 6);
     MD5STEP(F4, d, a, b, c, in[7] + 0x432aff97, 10);
     MD5STEP(F4, c, d, a, b, in[14] + 0xab9423a7, 15);
     MD5STEP(F4, b, c, d, a, in[5] + 0xfc93a039, 21);
     MD5STEP(F4, a, b, c, d, in[12] + 0x655b59c3, 6);
     MD5STEP(F4, d, a, b, c, in[3] + 0x8f0ccc92, 10);
     MD5STEP(F4, c, d, a, b, in[10] + 0xffeff47d, 15);
     MD5STEP(F4, b, c, d, a, in[1] + 0x85845dd1, 21);
     MD5STEP(F4, a, b, c, d, in[8] + 0x6fa87e4f, 6);
     MD5STEP(F4, d, a, b, c, in[15] + 0xfe2ce6e0, 10);
     MD5STEP(F4, c, d, a, b, in[6] + 0xa3014314, 15);
     MD5STEP(F4, b, c, d, a, in[13] + 0x4e0811a1, 21);
     MD5STEP(F4, a, b, c, d, in[4] + 0xf7537e82, 6);
     MD5STEP(F4, d, a, b, c, in[11] + 0xbd3af235, 10);
     MD5STEP(F4, c, d, a, b, in[2] + 0x2ad7d2bb, 15);
     MD5STEP(F4, b, c, d, a, in[9] + 0xeb86d391, 21);

     buf[0] += a;
     buf[1] += b;
     buf[2] += c;
     buf[3] += d;
 }
```

more details please follow [this](http://luau.sourceforge.net/api/html/md5_8h.html#_details)